# Is there a std::noncopyable (or equivalent)?

Tags: c++, standard-library

There's a [boost::noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html) and I have my own noncopyable class in my library.  Is there a std::noncopyable or equivalent knocking around in the latest C++ standard?

It's a small thing but deriving from such a class makes the intention much clearer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, because there is a standard way to make a class non-copyable:

```
class MyClass
{
   MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
   MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
}:
```

A class that is non-copyable can however be made movable by overloading a constructor from `MyClass&&`.

The declaration to make the class non-copyable (above) can be in the public or private section.

If you don't really want to type all that out every time, you can always define a macro something like:

```
#define NONCOPYABLE(Type) Type(const Type&)=delete; Type& operator=(const Type&)=delete

class MyClass
{
    NONCOPYABLE(MyClass);

    // etc.
};
```

Comment: You need to delete a copy-assignemnt operator as well to make the class non-copyable

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I added that to my answer before seeing your comment but well that makes it non-assignable.

Comment: OK about those move semantics.  They don't physically move the object somewhere else do they - the compiler is simply transferring the reference?  So when you say assignment, you mean copy I assume (just for clarification).

Comment: moving can be implemented like "swap" or it can leave 2 copies that look the same but the original item no longer has "ownership" so when it is deleted it doesn't delete the data. The state of the moved object must be stable but doesn't have any other guarantees. The state of the moved-to object should be the same as the moved one was.

Comment: *"but well that makes it non-assignable"* so assignmant is not a copy operation? `boost::noncopyable` won't let you copy-assign one instance to another

Comment: Indeed boost::noncopyable also makes the class non-assignable. Usually you want to disable that when you don't allow copying.

Comment: So in conclusion then, funnily enough, the "standard C++ way" of doing it is fraught with trouble, mostly because developers aren't 100% sure how they should do it.  I mean if I were to do this again I'd go google it.   I think there's a definite need for it in the standard library.

Answer (score 25):

I'm sure you already figured it out by reading CashCow's post, but I thought I might as well provide a base class for noncopyable classes.

```
class Noncopyable {
public:
    Noncopyable() = default;
    ~Noncopyable() = default;

private:
    Noncopyable(const Noncopyable&) = delete;
    Noncopyable& operator=(const Noncopyable&) = delete;
};
```

Comment: This is what Scott Meyers recommends (page 39 Effective C++ 3rd ed.)

Comment: I think making the deleted methods as 'public' instead of 'private' would be better so that the compiler would first complain about the use of deleted function rather than access to private function.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee5ef146f1a9b24c

Comment: Shouldn't the destructor be virtual?

Comment: @user2452809 this would all depend on the usage of the class.  If you're handing around a "Noncopyable" and then deleting it; sure.  If you're passing around a "NoncopyableDerived" then no.

Comment: @why is the destructor needed at all? Isn't it defaulted unless provided explicitly?

Comment: There is no need to put the NonCopyable into private when it uses =delete it works wherever it is defined. Therefore it's simpler to make a macro if you don't want to write it out every time.

Comment: The default constructor and destructor should be `protected`, since it would make no sense to instantiate an object of `Noncopyable` directly, only (notionally) as a base class of some derived, actually useful type.

Comment: That said, a macro is basically never the answer, and I don't see how it is desirable here.